# How to show the same exact form again after hiding it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a windows form program. That uses a login screen first then it proceeds to the main window, with the option to logout from there and login as another user.

When I use the logout option, how would I show the same hidden login form from before? I feel like it's a waste of memory to create a new LogInForm from scratch.

Comment: Usually, you never want to keep a form in memory if it is not used...

Comment: _" it's a waste of memory"_, more specifically _GDI resources_, to keep GUI objects laying about if you aren't using them.  Regardless to the amount of RAM in your computer, there is a set limit for GDI.  Maybe you mean _waste of CPU_ to recreate the window?  (it would have to be a pretty hefty login window though)

Answer (score 1):

LoginForm.Show() works fine but it will load the previously entered details if you did not dispose the form after a successful login. 
Also, there is no "waste of memory" in calling a form or creating it again.

Comment: You have to be careful with that last statement. If the developer creates a few forms and keeps retaining their references after closing, the objects will not be disposed for the lifecycle of the app potentially resulting in OutOfMemoryException's.

Comment: @zaitsman thats why i asked him to dispose. If the form is disposed and created it have no tie to memory consumption. Obviously there are differences between .close() and .dispose()

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply call `.Show()` again on the first form (provided you retain a reference to it somewhere within the app). Of course, practically speaking, you need to look at how frequently the users will perform this specific functionality. At a guess, creating a new login form maybe totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this In your MainForm:

```
Form2 f2;
public void Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    f2 = new Form2();
}
```

Wherever you want (In form1) use f2.Show(); or f2.ShowDialog();

In Form2, when you close the form, use this.Hide();

Hope this help!